# Issues with undefined variable after login

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I have a project on Laravel 5.7 where I create a custom admin (admin.blade.php) page after login, just adding the column userlevel on my Users table, and I have the next foreach on my admin.blade

**admin.blade.php**

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
 <h3><b>{{$customer->count('id')}}</b></h3>
 @break
@endforeach
```

Everything is ok when I do it the login on my page, but IF I close the page and I try to open again with the URL (example: http://192.168.1.125:8010/) the project show me the next error:

> Undefined variable: customers (View:
> D:\ExamplePage\system\resources\views\admin.blade.php) Undefined
> variable: customers (0)

**routes/web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    if($user = Auth::user())
    {
        if(Auth::user()->userlevel == "admin"){
            return view('/admin');
        }

    }

    return view('/auth/login');
});

Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index')->name('admin');
```

**HomeController.php**

```
use App\customers;
use App\pawns;

public function index()
    {
        $customers = customers::all();
        $pawns = pawns::all();
        return view('admin', compact('customers'), ['customers' => $customers,'pawns'=>$pawns]);
    }
```

**RedirectIfAuthenticated.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            if ($guard == 'admin') {
                return redirect()->route('/admin');
            }
         
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

How can I solve to everything that I open again the URL, this show me the admin.blade.php if I logged and dont show me the error with the variable $customers

Thanks

Comment: can you also please paste your route file here?

Answer (score 1):

That is because it unable to customer variable, compact is php function to merge array, and third parameter is used to merged Data , you don't need to pass a third parament, Instead Update the code in your home controller  like this.

```
use App\customers;
use App\pawns;

public function index()
    {
        $customers = customers::all();
        $pawns = pawns::all();
        return view('admin',['customers'=>$customers,'pawns'=>$pawns]);
            Or
       return view('admin',compact('customers','pawns'));
    }
```

Comment: `compact('customers', 'pawns')` would be shorthand for that repetitive array…